# VS2017 Bootstrapper: Engine/setup.bin missing

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, clickonce

I have moved to a new machine and upgraded with this MSVC 2015 to MSVC2017. Now I wanted to build a new (WiX) installer for our project. But I don't find current Bootstrapper location.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper` does not include `Engine/setup.bin`, which WiX will have.

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299) is installed.

Any idea which software I have to install to obtain required setup.bin? (Searched my whole PC for a setup.bin, but not a single setup.bin exists, so it's not just on a "wrong" oath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not sure why you refer to **ClickOnce** and **WiX** together - I am not aware of any connections here - they are different technologies - but maybe there are connections I am not aware of (something relating to AppX maybe).

The file you refer to: `setup.bin` is installed via two MSI files on my system:

- `Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi.msi` (installed from source at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2)
- `Microsoft.ClickOnce.SignTool.Msi.msi` (installed from source at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.ClickOnce.SignTool.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2)

Did you go to `Tools => Get Tools and Features => Individual Components` and select "**ClickOnce Publishing**"? I would try that first. There is no clear match between the actual MSI names and these "Individual Components" that I can see.

---

I believe "**Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects**", "**WiX Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extensions**" and "**IsWiX**" (front end for WiX) can be installed from the `Tools => Extension and Updates`. Or you can install [the WiX 2017 extension from here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension).

You also obviously need to install the WiX toolkit itself to be able to make WiX installers. Here is the download location: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/ (and [a WiX quick start suggestion answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)).

Comment: Thanks "ClickOnce Publishing" was missing. After installing it I have all files I need :). Btw: There exists no real connection between ClickOnce and WiX, except I use Clicke Once Bootstrapper file via BootstrapperFile in my wixproj